# Need help with Javascript Replace Bookmarklet

Tags: javascript

I've searched the other questions and tried the suggestions but i still couldn't implement my bookmarklet successfully. Any suggestions on my code below will be appreciated. My goal is to get the script capture the current text selection via `document.getSelection()` and then replace all the dots with plus sign (it's for a task that has a few dots for each row of data).

```
javascript:(function(){ 

  var stringselect = null;

  function replaceString (text) {
    text = text.replace('.','+');
    return text; 
  } 

  var stringselect = document.getSelection();
  var result = replaceString(stringselect);

  alert(result); //for testing purposes, i wanted to see the replaced text in the alert box but it didn't pop up.
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said *how* it doesn't work, but one thing jumps out at me:

```
text = text.replace('.','+');
```

That will only replace the *first* `.`. If you want to replace all of them, you have to use a regular expression rather than a string for the "find" argument, and you need to set the "global" flag on the regex:

```
text = text.replace(/\./g,'+');
```

(You need the backslash before the `.` because `.` is special in a regex, but you're actually looking for a real `.`, so we escape it.) The `/` delimit the regex literal, and the `g` is the "global" flag.

Separately: I think you mean [`window.getSelection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.getSelection), not `document.getSelection`, and note that IE doesn't support it [until IE9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975169%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). If you need to get text selections reliably cross-browser, you're in for some work. There's a handy library called [rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) that can help.

Comment: thanks for explaining. I've tried the following code  based on @mplungjan's suggestion but the alert box didn't pop up. I used document.getSelection() for my another bookmarket and it works fine. javascript:(function(){ var stringselect = document.getSelection(); var result = stringselect.replace(/\./g,'+'); alert(result); })();

Answer (score 0):

Crossbrowser now

`javascript:(function(){  var userSelection; if (window.getSelection) { userSelection = window.getSelection().toString();} else if (document.selection) { rng = document.selection.createRange(); userSelection =rng?rng.text:"ie borked"} var result = (userSelection)?userSelection.replace(/\./g,'+'):"Nothing replaced";  alert(result); })();`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I've tried the following code javascript:(function(){ var stringselect = document.getSelection(); var result = stringselect.replace(/\./g,'+'); alert(result); })(); but the alert box didn't pop up.

Comment: Works for me - however please note that in Fx6+ you need to test this as a real bookmark or from the console since they have stopped allowing arbitrary JS from the location bar

Comment: @user930286 I made it cross browser now